# ASP.NET MVC Deployed Application Error 'Could not find a part of the path C:\Users\UserName\Documents\FileName.xlsx' Only in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, iis-8

Hi I Have a MVC application that uploads a file to the server, all works fine on my local machine, as soon as I deploy to the server, it only works in Chrome and not in IE. The application reads a file and saves it on the server, I have added given. I have given the correct permissions to the Network Service to access the folder. Although when I run the application outside of the server in IE it fails with the above error. Please assist, any ideas? Please see code below.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        List<CleanSupplierClaim> supplierClaimsData = new List<CleanSupplierClaim>();

        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {


                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);




                var targetPath = Server.MapPath("~/upload");

                file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName));
```

Here is my app pool config, set as the local system

[image]

And here is the folder permission setting.

[image]

I have allocated the correct permissions for the user reading file from users machine, which in my case is the Network Service. Although in IE it throws an exception 'Could not find a part of the path **'**'

How can I fix this issue, I have ran out of ideas. My IIS version is 8.5

Comment: Do you have compatibility mode enabled on Internet Explorer? Not saying this is the cause, but I've done lots of cross browser dev at my job, and this has become a recurring annoyance.

Comment: Yes, I do. In-fact that is handles using Group PO on the server. My site is hosted under our wildcard.

Comment: Do you have the ability to try to disable that and re-try?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What if Writing: var targetPath = Server.MapPath("/upload");

Server.MapPath("~") returns the physical path to the root of the application
Server.MapPath("/") returns the physical path to the root of the domain name (is not necessarily the same as the root of the application)